# After workout: meal or protein shake or both?

Tags: weightlifting, diet, protein-shakes

Im a little unsure about one thing. After the weightlifting, should I have only meal or both the meal and shake?

My shake is: 30gram protein and 227 cals.
My meal is around: 500 cals, 32 gram protein and half avocado + 1 glass milk or water.
I eat 5 meals per day. 500 cals each.

Am I not wasting if I intake both of them?

Comment: Are you trying to gain weight, lose weight, maintain, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends.**

Are you getting enough protein from your meals? If not, drink the protein shake. Personally, since I need to get about 190g of protein each day I typically have a post workout shake along with any meals I need to eat in order to maintain my daily calories/macros.